# How to test this method using XUnit and Moq?

Tags: c#, .net, testing, moq, xunit

```
[HttpPost("GetRefusalPdf")]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetRefusalPdf([FromBody] DispatchRefusal? refusal)
{
    if (refusal == null) return StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status406NotAcceptable);
    // Log the API endpoint, datetime, and client IP
    await _loggingFactory.LogApiRequests(HttpContext);
    var pdfStreamData = await _dispatchRefusalService.GenerateEtsRefusalFormAsync(refusal);
    
    return File(pdfStreamData, "application/pdf", $"Refusal-{refusal.PatientName}-{refusal.RefusalDateTime.ToString("yy-MM-dd")}.pdf");
}
```

Need help writing an Xunit Test for this method.

I started using this test method

```
[Fact]
public async Task GetRefusalPdfReturnsFile()
{
  var controller = new DispatchRefusalController();

  var result = await controller.GetRefusalPdf(refusal: new DispatchRefusal());
  File? okResult = result as File;
}
```

Comment: And what is the problem with your test?

Comment: @SirRufo At a glance, I'd say that it lacks an assertion 

Comment: @MarkSeemann Ok, we are on assumptions: This test code will not reach any assertion, because it will not compile at all

Comment: This is error I'm getting "Cannot assign 'System.IO.File?' to an implicitly-typed local variable"

Answer (score 1):

I don't get the error reported in the OP but rather this compiler error:

> CS0723 Cannot declare a variable of static type 'File'

This, at least, is because the [File](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.io.file) class *is* a `static` class (used to perform file operations).

Depending on the overload, the [File](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.controllerbase.file) *method* returns a [FileContentResult](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.filecontentresult), [VirtualFileResult](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.virtualfileresult), etc. This particular overload seems to return [FileStreamResult](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.filestreamresult), so try this instead:

```
FileStreamResult? okResult = result as FileStreamResult;
```

That said, since you're using xUnit.net, consider using `Assert.IsAssignableFrom` instead:

```
var actual = Assert.IsAssignableFrom<FileStreamResult>(result);
```